# Possible to give Ajax Permission to site not in Same Origin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, uri, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to take a p - for example - element from one of my websites on **Server 1**
and insert it inside a `<div id="insert"></div>` element from a website on **Server 2**

I'm trying to do this using the load function
 `$(  '#insert' ).load('server1.com/index #take p')`

Issue is: [image]

**Since I have access to both servers, is there anyway to allow these request to happen?**

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Cross Origin HTTP Request. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

You may be able to accomplish what you want by adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
</ifModule>
```

But read through the link for more details.